Sms Auto fill and read in Flutter iOS
I am doing Otp with sms code. I added two packages that called   sms_autofill: and otp_autofill: I wrote all code in view. I am receiving otp code but it doesn't fill auto. I see on top keyboard my code. I confused how I can solve that issue. My device is receiving code but app doesn't read and fill auto. I give permission in info.plist
I got error Bad state: No element
class PhoneNumberOtp extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  String phoneNumber = '';
  String otpCode = "";
  String otp = "";

  PhoneNumberOtp({super.key, required this.phoneNumber});
  @override
    _PhoneNumberOtpState createState() => _PhoneNumberOtpState();
  }

  @override
  class _PhoneNumberOtpState   extends ConsumerState<PhoneNumberOtp> {
  void initState() {
_listenOtp();
super.initState();
  }
  void _listenOtp() async {
    await SmsAutoFill().listenForCode();
    SmsAutoFill().code.listen((code) {
      setState(() {
       widget.otpCode = code;
      });
    });
    print("OTP Listen is called");
  }
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      final phoneOtpProviderMethods = ref.watch(phoneOtpProvider.notifier);
      final phoneOtpStates = ref.watch(phoneOtpProvider);

      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      
                      _buildPinFieldFill(phoneOtpProviderMethods, context),
                      const SizedBox(height: 15),
                      _buildSaveButton(phoneOtpStates, context),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      _buildCancelButton(context),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

   
    SizedBox _buildSaveButton(PhoneNumberOtpState phoneOtpStates, BuildContext context) {
      return SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            phoneOtpStates.loading == true
                ? const ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: null,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 24,
                height: 24,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            )
                : const SizedBox.shrink(),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: phoneOtpStates.loading == true
                    ? null
                    : () {
                  //phoneOtpProviderMethods.verifyCode(concatenatedText, phoneNumber, context);
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Theme
                      .of(context)
                      .colorScheme
                      .background,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                ),
                child: const Text(
                  'Telefonu Doğrula',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    PinFieldAutoFill _buildPinFieldFill(PhoneNumberOtpProvider phoneOtpProviderMethods, BuildContext context) {
      return PinFieldAutoFill(
        decoration: BoxLooseDecoration(
          strokeColorBuilder: PinListenColorBuilder(Colors.black, Colors.black26),
          bgColorBuilder: const FixedColorBuilder(Colors.white),
          strokeWidth: 1.2,
        ),
        currentCode: widget.otpCode,
        onCodeSubmitted: (code) {},
        onCodeChanged: (code) {
          widget.otpCode = code.toString();
          if (code?.length == 6) {
            Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
              phoneOtpProviderMethods.verifyCode(code!, widget.phoneNumber, context);
            });
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }

I tried add permission and some solution in initstate

On iOS the user needs to tap the code on the quick type bar to enter it into the field. There is no way to have the code entered without user interaction.

you mean iOs doesn't allow auto fill

Correct. The user needs to tap the code if they want to enter it.
